# How to sum up table rows group by storage_id and product_id

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying the following problem : I am sharing the table image first(from where the rows will be summed up)

[image]

When the api is Hit, It should first group the `storage_id`, then `product_id` and then sum up `quanitity` of same `product_id`

for example :

there are two `storage_id` : 1 & 2 , two different `product_id` : 1 & 2 . Now the output should be `sum all the rows where storage_id, where product_id`. there should be 3 JSON outputs, for storage 1 & product 1, for storage 1 & product 2. for storage 2 & product 2. And they should be then stored in a table like the following table

[image]

My code so far ( from the controller ) :

```
$storages = Storage::get(); // getting storage list

foreach($storages as $storage => $val){
    $storage_id[] =  $storages[$storage]->id; // Getting array of id only
    $get_storage[] = Storage::with('storageProducts')->whereIn('id', $storage_id)->get();

    foreach($get_storage as $product => $val){

         foreach($val as $d){
            $a[$d->id] = StorageProduct::where('transfer_type',1)
                         ->where('storage_id',$d->id)
                         ->groupBy('storage_id', 'product_id')
                         ->sum('quantity');
         }
    }
}
```

The output I am getting :

```
{
    "1": 28,
    "2": 23
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$result = StorageProduct::where('transfer_type',1)
    ->select('storage_id', 'product_id', DB::raw('SUM(quantity) as stock'))
    ->groupBy('storage_id', 'product_id')
    ->get();
```

Comment: It's returning the same result

Comment: I have updated the question with output (at bottom)

Comment: Got it, updated my query, should be what you need

Answer (score 0):

SELECT  storage_id , product_id ,SUM(stock) as stock   FROM `tb_stock`  GROUP BY product_id , storage_id

Comment: I am trying with your code